# Поиск индексов минимального и максимального элементов массива

Tags: java, массивы

Есть методы, которые находят максимальный и минимальный элементы массива.
Как найти индексы этих элементов?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class F {
    static double max = 0;
    private static double array[] = { 0.22, 0.4, 0.92, 1.5, 1.99, 4.5 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findMax(array);
        findMin(array);
    }

    public static void findMax(double[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array);
        max = array[array.length - 1];
        System.out.println(max);
    }

    public static void findMin(double[] array) {
        double min = array[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < array[0]) {
                min = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(min);
    }

    public static void findIndexOfMax() {
       //код метода, который находит и возвращает индексы
       // максимального и минимального элементов массива
    }
}
```

Comment: Занятно, кстати, что для поиска максимума вы воспользовались `Arrays.sort()`, а для поиска минимума - нет, хотя там сделать так же: `Arrays.sort(array); double min = array[0];`.

Comment: Точно, спасибо за совет, а то я  совсем не подумала

Comment: На здоровье. Но, повторюсь, для поиска мин. и макс. элементов в массиве сортировка массива не является оптимальным решением, да к тому же она ещё и "портит" массив. По-хорошему, минимум и максимум нужно искать так же, как и их индексы. Или, например, находить индексы, а по ним сразу получать сами значения (ведь `array[indexOfMax]` и есть `max`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно, конечно, отсортировать массив по возрастанию с помощью `Arrays.sort()` (тогда минимальный элемент будет иметь индекс `0`, а максимальный - `array.length - 1`), но сортировка массива и его изменение ради поиска значений не является оптимальным решением.

Индексы минимального и максимального элементов можно найти за линейное время, не изменяя массив:

```
double[] array = { 0.22, 0.4, 0.92, 1.5, 1.99, 4.5 };
int indexOfMax = 0;
int indexOfMin = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > array[indexOfMax])
    {
        indexOfMax = i;
    }
    else if (array[i] < array[indexOfMin])
    {
        indexOfMin = i;
    }
}
System.out.println(indexOfMax + " " + indexOfMin);
```

Answer (score 1):

За столько времени никто не увидел, что метод `findMin` работает некорректно?

Тестируйте `{ 10.2, 2.2, 2.5 }`. Только не `(array[i] < array[0])`, а `(array[i] < min)`